# in2csv: iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row_offset'

Tags: openpyxl, csvkit

I'm using in2csv from csvkit version 1.0.3, installed using pip with Python 3.7.

When using the tool for the most basic conversion task i.e.

```
in2csv filename.xlsx > test.csv
```

I was hit with error

```
iter_rows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row_offset'
```

I understand that the error was reported by the underlying library openpyxl. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Could you share your input file?

Comment: Report this as a bug on the csvkit bugtracker.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `row_offset` parameter inside iter_rows() has already been deprecated as of openpyxl version 2.6.0 last 6th Feb, 2019. I tried looking at the commit history and saw the following changes:
 https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/diff/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py?diff1=e4ec3bde4dcc&diff2=3294de3d5668f462baaa6b0a3c17e3b92b8e5c48&at=default

To fix this, you must no longer use the `row_offset` and adjust your `min_row` and `max_row` accordingly.

e.g.

If you're processing only the 4th row of the worksheet:

```
# old code
rows = worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=3, max_row=1)

# new 
rows = worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=4, max_row=4)
```

If you're processing the rows starting from the 2nd row:

```
# old 
rows = worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=1, max_row=(worksheet.max_row - 1)

# new 
rows = worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=worksheet.max_row)
```

I actually like this change even though it broke my codes. I think using `min_row` and `max_row` makes the code more readable and intuitive rather than using the `row_offset`.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this problem myself, looks to me like a change in openpyxl has broken in2csv.

I've fixed this by uninstalling openpyxl and reinstalling an older version.

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
pip install openpyxl==2.5
```

Or in the case that, like me, you are installing this all from scratch, just install openpyxl 2.5 before installing csv kit

```
pip install openpyxl==2.5
pip install csvkit
```